# unexpected error occurred on a service, An existing connection was forcibly closed be a remote host

Tags: c#, asp.net, service

unexpected error occurred on a service, An existing connection was forcibly closed be a remote host, attached error message for more details. Any help to resolve the issue would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Kumar
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was recently getting errors like this from a web service when I had not configured it correctly to handle enough data eg: maxBufferPoolSize, maxReceivedMessageSize and the like.

In the httpbinding section of the client side app.config and server web.config.

Also if you are sending a large array the service behaviour and endpoint behavior sections of these files may need:

```
<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="array size here"/>
```

Comment: can you explain maxBufferPoolSize, maxReceivedMessageSize in detail, where to configure in service or client.

Comment: For your information, I am not using WCF services I am using asp.net webservices.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of these links will help:

[Unable to read data from the transport connection : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420656/error-at-system-io-ioexception-unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connectio)

[An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582036/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host)

[C# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host: socket programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389401/c-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host-socket-programm)